# Choose what set of values a picklist draws from based on another picklist

Tags: picklist, dependent-picklist, dynamic-picklist

here's our situation:

- We want to associate an Account with multiple counties throughout the US (and these counties could come from multiple states)
- Ideally we'd have one giant multi-select picklist of "Counties" that has 3,000+ values and is filtered based on another dependent field that specifies state (e.g. choosing "New York" in "Field: State" would filter the multi-select picklist to only counties in New York)
- Unfortunately, you can't have a picklist with 3,000+ records
- One workaround we're considering if: (1) we make 50 picklists, one for each state, and the values for each are the respective counties of its state. (2) A separate field specifies state. (3) We display all 50 picklists on a record, but set their conditional visibility such that they only appear if the field in (2) is set to their state. (4) we then have a third field that adds up all of the counties selected.
- This workaround, however, isn't ideal for a bunch of records.

— Is there another way to approach this? Stated another way: How would you go about enabling someone to choose what counties their Account is associated with, when every single county in the US could be an option?

Thanks!

Comment: Dependent picklists exist: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_dependent_fields.htm&type=5

Comment: A dependent picklist doesn't really work here for two reasons: (1) we can't have the dependent field contain every county in the US (as you can't have picklists with more than 3000 values), which means (2) we'd need to make 50 picklists (one for each state) that are all dependent to the state controlling field (this is what I describe above). This would work, but doesn't seem great.

Comment: What makes it not great, one-time generation of lists? List of US states doesn't change often, last change was in 1959. County boundaries might change but [list of counties per state](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/geography/technical-documentation/county-changes.html) is fairly static.

Comment: Not concerned with counties changing. What makes it not great is the implementation — we'd need to have 50 picklists on the record, selecting counties across states creates complexities, and we'd have to create a third field that adds up all the counties selected. Seems like there should be something more elegant here rather than creating 52 new fields (50 states + dependent picklist + field that adds up every county selected)